# insert с dateTime в sqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Помогите пожалуйста с запросом:

```
insert into ефиду
(ID_ST, CONTROLLER, DATE_COMPL, SUM_DOG, PERFORMER, DATE_CONTR, NOTATE) 
values ('1','3',convert(datetime,'14.08.2018 0:00:00',4),'text','text',convert(datetime,'16.08.2018 0:00:00',5),'')
```

Ошибка: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert(datetime,'14.08.2018 00:00:00',104)